# Android EditText InputMethodManager got newline in input string

Tags: android, android-edittext

i am launching a dialog with a text edit in. i want the keyboard to pop up when i touch the text edit field and when i hit return, i want it to go away.

well i got that here

```
        final EditText commentTextEdit = new EditText(context);
        commentTextEdit.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        commentTextEdit.setOnTouchListener(new EditText.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                commentTextEdit.setFocusableInTouchMode(true); 
                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(commentTextEdit.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS );
                return false;
            }
        });
        commentTextEdit.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                String s = commentTextEdit.getText().toString();
                Log.d("Dialogs", "BarOptionsDialog got input "+s);
                if(s.contains("\n"))
                    Log.d("Dialogs", "BarOptionsDialog found new line");
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(commentTextEdit.getWindowToken(), 0);
                return false;
            }
        });
        commentTextEdit.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
        innerlayout.addView(commentTextEdit);
```

the only problem is, i don't want a \n in the string. setOnEditorActionListener onEditorAction is triggered when i hit return but when i look at the string, there is no \n in there

yet when setOnEditorActionListener onEditorAction finishes, the \n appears in the edit text which i don't want.

anyone know how to stop that?

thanks

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: did you play with the return value? you can distinguish Enter from other keys via event or actionId.

Comment: @user370305 i added the follow to the question 'yet when setOnEditorActionListener onEditorAction finishes, the \n appears in the edit text which i don't want.' does that make it clear what the problem is?

Comment: @18446744073709551615 that did it, i return true from onEditorAction and no it works great, no new line. do you want to answer my question?

Comment: You have to  `return true;` on `setOnEditorActionListener`.